# How do you get rid of emails in bulk in Office 365's Outlook?

Tags: email, office-365, outlook-on-the-web, outlook-365

I don't know if that's a bug or the normal behavior.

[image]

I have **2388** emails in my Office 365 Inbox. If I proceed to a search among them using the string 'Goldilocks', all the emails with this word in the subject or content will be displayed.

If I select them all using this checkbox:

[image]

then this appears on my screen:

[image]

(notice how it only selected 9 conversations).

Then I delete them by pressing either the first link in the previous screenshot or this one on top of the screen:

[image]

Then I go back to the Inbox folder:

[image]

And in my Inbox, the number is still **2388** emails, as if the 'Goldilocks' emails I selected in the previous step, and deleted, were not deleted.

[image]

Even if I click "more" to display more folders, I cannot find a "Trash" to empty or look inside.

### Questions

1 - How do I select more than 9 emails in a search result? (i.e., all the emails in a search result)

2 - After selecting ALL the emails in the results, how can I then proceed to delete them completely in as few steps as possible? (and by that I mean *delete them, empty the trash, make them vanish from view, take the number out of the total number displayed next to my Inbox*?)

3 - What does "Delete" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find solutions on the web for your other questions on selecting multiple emails and rule creation but this one seems to be a known problem with Outlook on Web. I've found a few similar questions and feature requests from Microsoft.

I've tried to select multiple emails from my own search results. I've did somehow manage to do it but can't exactly put my finger on the proper process. It's a little bit cumbersome but this was the only way that I was able to select multiple items (or all items) from a search result.

I'll try to write down the process.

1. Search your string
2. Select the first few 4-5 emails all together from the search results by using the Shift key
3. Scroll the list down just for a few emails (Something like 10-20-30. More than that does somehow break down the process)
4. Select an email from the scrolled list by pressing the Shift key
5. All the emails between the first group and the selected email will be selected. You can further scroll the search results and select more emails with this method by considering the 10-20-30 item scrolling limit. Don't be alarmed if you've accidentally scrolled too much down. If the selected email doesn't refresh the total selected email count you can always scroll back up and select another mail. The total selected email list won't reset.
6. You can do all the possible actions on this group from the central menu or from the right button menu

Comment: I noticed this behavior too. Super strange and cumbersome as you said. I think for the rest the app was confused calculating the number of emails that were unread since it doesn't seem to fetch them unless you scroll to them (which also might explain why we can't select so many emails at once)

Answer (score 1):

(Using the online Office 365 Outlook)

If you have a lot of emails to remove a better way is to create a rule that moves all the emails containing the search term "Goldilocks" into the Deleted Items folder.

A safer method would be to create a folder and move them into that, then you can check them before selecting the "Delete All" button.

Comment: This does not work retroactively on existing emails, only on new emails.