# How do I select more than 9 Inbox items (but less than all the emails) in Office 365's Outlook?

Tags: office-365, outlook-on-the-web

When I try to select several emails in Outlook within Office 365, here is what happens:

I can select **9 emails** (or 13 emails if I disable the preview text in the preferences) if I click on the first one displayed and then shift-click the last one displayed.

But if I select one, then scroll to the top of the list and then shift-click, nothing happens.

Is it possible to select more emails in one go than the number of emails displayed on the screen?

Comment: I can confirm this problem. I can't scroll down and shift-click more than about 25 messages. It may be refreshing the list (I can see a jump in the display of the list), and then something goes wrong. It actually works ok if you switch to the light version of Outlook 365 in the general options for mail.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to select multiple emails on Outlook on Web. I myself wasn't aware of the process until I've found similar answers to [this one](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=41546). I've tried this solution and it worked.

1. Click on a message

[image]

2. Hold down the Ctrl key on your keyboard and select another message. You can select as many messages as you'd like while holding down Ctrl.
   *Note:  Holding down Shift and trying to select a string of messages after using Ctrl will un-select the already selected messages.*

[image]

3. To select what to do with the messages, you can either right-click on one of the messages and select the desired action or you can click and drag them to the desired folder.
   *Note: The email content window also contains a menu for all the possible actions for the selected emails.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: My question asks "more than 9 items", do you think you could try to select, say 100 emails in one go for me? I'm wondering if it's only me or other users have this problem...

Comment: In theory it should work for all the emails if you scroll to the bottom of your email list and select the last email while holding down the Shift key as it's already expressed in the answer but strangely the list scrolling limitation from my [answer to your bulk deletion question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/95815) applies to this action, too.

Comment: Yes, the process of selecting a batch of emails, then scrolling - but not too much - then holding shift and selecting again is what I'm going with right now… weird and annoying but hey it's not like Microsoft can afford good developers :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Disable preview text in options. I also enabled light version in options, not sure if this has an effect.
Then I really zoom out the current view. This allows me to select 100+ items.

[image]

After this, you can still zoom in to access the controls again.

Also if you didn't know, after selecting "all", you can further select "everything", which is selecting every item in the folder, but then you have only a limited set of actions:
[image]